# What is the difference between the AQL EDGES, NEIGHBORS, etc. and GRAPH_EDGES, GRAPH_NEIGHBORS

Tags: arangodb

In ArangoDB, there seem to be two set of functions for working with graphs. One one side you have `EDGES`, `NEIGHBORS`, `TRAVERSAL`, `SHORTEST_PATH` and more.

On the other hand, there are the graph operations that seem to have the same functions prefixed by `GRAPH` and with some different parameters, such as `GRAPH_EDGES`, `GRAPH_NEIGHBORS`, `GRAPH_TRAVERSAL`, `GRAPH_SHORTEST_PATH`.

What is the difference between these? Are they used in different scenarios? Are there performance differences, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: These graph-related functions no longer exist and have been superseded by a language construct for graph traversals and path-finding algorithms in the AQL query language: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/graphs/

---

There is no general recommendation on which to choose over the other - it depends on your requirements.

The EDGES functions can be used for collections that are not managed by the graph module, and thus may not be visible in the graph viewer (but you may use them on collections that are also managed). It however has lesser overhead by not doing graph management.

The GRAPH_EDGES family is the more recent implementation. It only works on managed graphs that you can also browse in the graph viewer. As you already noted, the latter have many more options to e.g. filter the graphs by examples etc.

In ArangoDB 3.0, the GRAPH_* family of functions was removed and there are better alternatives now for most of them.